# Occasional 403 CSRF error in React Native WebView

Tags: django, react-native, webview, csrf

I am loading a form (powered by Django) in a React Native app using `react-native-webview`. This form has CSRF protection. And most of the time it actually works fine, you can submit the form in the app through the webview and everything is fine. But sometimes I get a 403 CSRF error (CSRF verification failed, Request aborted).

I'm not sure what could be causing this and how could it be avoided? I'm using the `WebView` in a fairly straightforward way with a wrapper around it.

If there was a network connection issue on the mobile phone then I would probably get a timeout error instead right, not something specific like this?

```
import { WebView as BaseWebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const FullScreenWebView = styled(BaseWebView)`
  flex: 1;
`;
...
export const WebView: FC<WebViewProps> = props => {
...
return (
    <Layout.Root>
      {url.startsWith('/') ? (
        <Layout.LoadingFlex1 />
      ) : (
        <FullScreenWebView
          ref={webviewRef}
          source={{ uri: urlWithLang }}
          startInLoadingState={true}
          onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={globalZendeskIntercept}
          // only allow secure webviews and those for our deeplink scheme
          originWhitelist={['https://', `${Config.DEEPLINK_SCHEME}://`]}
          decelerationRate="normal"
          allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures
          onNavigationStateChange={navState => {
            if (navState.canGoBack) {
              setCanGoBack(true);
            } else {
              setCanGoBack(false);
            }
          }}
        />
      )}
    </Layout.Root>
  );
};
```

Comment: try having a look at this thread : https://spectrum.chat/react-native/general/react-native-django-rest-api-403-error-csrf~3977f578-0115-4f5e-8eb4-1da3569e82dd

Comment: csrf verification fails if a csrf token is not submitted or it is submitted multiple times.
in your case because it only occurs sometimes i guess it might be the second scenario.
You can try disabling the button once the form is submitted to disable multiple submits.

Comment: @SukhpreetSingh The button is already disabled when you press it in my case so unfortunately, I don't think this is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem somewhat which turned out to be due to stale cookies in iOS WebView.

All I did was clear all the cookies before and after the WebView component was rendered to be sure.

```
import CookieManager from "@react-native-cookies/cookies";

...
    
useEffect(() => {
  CookieManager.clearAll().catch(console.error);

  return () => {
    CookieManager.clearAll().catch(console.error);
  };
}, []);

...

<WebView ... />
```

Maybe you can give it a try.